# Why is /proc/net/snmp not showing Udp InCSumErrors?

Tags: udp, oracle-linux, snmp

I'm running Oracle Linux 6.5, kernel 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64.

When I look at the Udp snmp stats it does not show me InCsumErrors. How can I see this stat?

---

```
cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Udp\:
Udp: InDatagrams NoPorts InErrors OutDatagrams RcvbufErrors SndbufErrors
Udp: 11572193686 14491 958123361 223700728 0 0
```

---

Whereas on my Oracle 7.4 VM it does:

```
cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Udp\:

Udp: InDatagrams NoPorts InErrors OutDatagrams RcvbufErrors SndbufErrors InCsumErrors IgnoredMulti
Udp: 0 64 0 94 0 0 0 0
```

---

My need is to understand what our InErrors are caused by. With zero RcvbufErrors, are my InErrors due to checksums? Or, as I've spotted in the kernel code, are they due to some other cases where UDP_MIB_INERRORS is incremented but neither UDP_MIB_RCVBUFERRORS nor UDP_MIB_CSUMERRORS are incremented?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Red Hat. InCSumErrors is supported in Oracle/RedH Hat 7, but not in 6.

The commit that added the snmp counter is:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=6a5dc9e59